# How to put database on azure website

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I recently finished my asp website, bought the domain and azure hosting. Unfortunately, when I try to do anything that accesses the database I just get stuck on a loading screen. I just used the default asp razor mvc 5 project I think for the database along with a couple of custom tables.

Comment: Do you have an existing database, or are you looking to stand up a new one? Also is it a SQL database?

Comment: It is a sql database. I want to copy an existing database, well the schema I don't care about the current values. Also I want it to just be on the server, not a full separate db server.

Answer (score 1):

So here is how I would do it since you have an existing database. I would follow azures website, and set up a SQL database. I would then script out the database on you local machine, and log into your azure database using SQL Server Express. Execute the script you generated from localDB. Then all of your data will be good to go. You will then need to take the connection string from azure, and put it in your applications config file. After modifying the connection string in your application you should redeploy, and verify everything is working the way you want. You will be able to verify your data is there in SQL Server Express.

Here is a [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/) that may be of quite a bit of assistance to you. It includes step by step instructions as well as screen shots.

Another option is using this [tool](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/). I have never used it, but I know a few people who have had great success with it.